# How do I adjust the position of lists and icons in them with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

```
class EditNoteList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String child;
  final IconData icon;
  EditNoteList({required this.child, required this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 400,
                color: Colors.cyan,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Center(
                        child: Text(
                      child,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(icon),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Here I am trying to set the design, position of the listView I want to show in the page.

```
    class EditNote extends StatelessWidget {
  final List _posts = [
    'List 1',
    'List 2',
    'List 3',
  ];
  final List<IconData> icons = [Icons.add, Icons.access_alarms, Icons.account_circle_outlined];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemCount: _posts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return EditNoteList(
                  icon: icons[index],
                  child: _posts[index],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I add the formatted lists to the page I want to show.

[image]

**How it looks on this page.**

[image]

**This is how I want it to appear on the page. Each icon is on the right in the list, and all the lists are in the middle of the page.**

Answer (score 0):

Using an empty widget with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,` can do the trick

```dart
Center(
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 400,
    color: Colors.cyan,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const SizedBox.shrink(),
        Center(
            child: Text(
          child,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        )),
        Icon(icon),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]